# How to check usage of different parts of memory?

Tags: linux, memory-management

I have computer with 2 Intel Xeon CPUs and 48 GB of RAM. RAM is divided between CPUs - two parts 24 GB + 24 GB. How can I check how much of each specific part is used?

So, I need something like `htop`, which shows how fully each core is used (see [this example](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_VN8zHqq8Ns8/SxIi11nNPPI/AAAAAAAADNo/o61_3eg9DOU/s1600/htop.png)), but rather for memory than for cores. Or something that would specify which part (addresses) of memory are used and which are not.

Comment: I'm not even sure the kernel has that information. I am pretty sure all the OS sees is a chunk of memory (maybe I am wrong).

Comment: "RAM is divided between CPUs" - how?

Comment: Robin Green, as I said, it's 24GB per CPU. Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information is in `/proc/zoneinfo`, contains very similar information to `/proc/vmstat` except broken down by "Node" (Numa ID). I don't have a NUMA system here to test it for you and provide a sample output for a multi-node config; it looks like this on a one-node machine:

```
Node 0, zone      DMA
pages free     2122
      min      16
      low      20
      high     24
      scanned  0
      spanned  4096
      present  3963
[ ... followed by /proc/vmstat-like nr_* values ]
Node 0, zone   Normal
pages free     17899
      min      932
      low      1165
      high     1398
      scanned  0
      spanned  223230
      present  221486
nr_free_pages 17899
nr_inactive_anon 3028
nr_active_anon 0
nr_inactive_file 48744
nr_active_file 118142
nr_unevictable 0
nr_mlock     0
nr_anon_pages 2956
nr_mapped    96
nr_file_pages 166957
[ ... more of those ... ]
Node 0, zone  HighMem
pages free     5177
      min      128
      low      435
      high     743
      scanned  0
      spanned  294547
      present  292245
[ ... ]
```

I.e. a small statistic on the usage/availability total followed by the `nr_*` values also found on a system-global level in `/proc/vmstat` (which then allow a further breakdown as of what exactly the memory is used for).

If you have more than one memory node, aka NUMA, you'll see these zones for all nodes.

### edit

I'm not aware of a frontend for this (i.e. a numa `vmstat` like `htop` is a numa-`top`), but please comment if anyone knows one !

Comment: FrankH., thanks a lot.  And could you help me to find some description of the zoneinfo lines?

Comment: This has the definitions: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob_plain;f=include/linux/mmzone.h;hb=HEAD

Comment: Beyond that, check the Linux kernel sources in `mm/vmstat.c` for how the data is printed / what is printed there. You'll find that `/proc/vmstat` has the same contents as `/proc/zoneinfo`, except summed over all zones.

Answer (score 2):

The `numactl --hardware` command will give you a short answer like this:

`node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5
node 0 size: 49140 MB
node 0 free: 25293 MB
node 1 cpus: 6 7 8 9 10 11
node 1 size: 49152 MB
node 1 free: 20758 MB
node distances:
node   0   1
  0:  10  21
  1:  21  10`